# Removing a html attribute added from razor or keep it from adding

Tags: html, css, asp.net-mvc, razor

I'm adding an input field via Razor

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.ccVersandkosten, new { @class = "form-control" })
```

but it adds some html attributes that I don't want:

```
<input class="form-control" data-val="true" data-val-number="Das Feld&quot;Versandkosten&quot; muss eine Zahl sein." data-val-required="Das Feld &quot;Versandkosten&quot; ist erforderlich." id="ccVersandkosten" name="ccVersandkosten" type="text" value="0" />
```

The attribute which I don't need is `value="0"`. I thinks Razor adds the `value` attribute because my variable `ccVersandkosten` is a float, I could change this but it needs to be a float.

Is there a way to remove this attribute or keep Razor from adding it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in your model you define it float. "Float" must not be null. When model initialize, then not-nullable variables initialize by 0. This is not a razor feature, this is c# feature.

So razor display this field as 0. You can define variable as nullable (`float? ccVersandkosten`) to display nothing for value attr.

`@model MyModel` means `var model = new MyModel();`, so when you create a new class, c# initialize the not-nullable variables. (float, int, double, datetime,..)

Comment: I made the varaibles nullable and it works fine now.

Answer (score 0):

Razor automatically sets the Value based on the property you are creating the textbox for (in this case x.ccVersandkosten). This is good.

If you want the initial value to be null, you must make ccVersandkosten nullable.

Answer (score 0):

Razor will add this attribute regardless of the type of your `ccVersandkosten` property. The `TextBoxFor` helper creates an `input` element and, since `input`s are usually meant for collecting data and sending it to the server, it must have a value.

If you don't need a value for your property, you're probably not using the correct helper. You have several options here: render your property using `HiddenFor` or, if you just want to display something, create a standard HTML `label`.

Judging from the generated validation code, your property may be decorated with the `[Required]` attribute. I only say "may", because all value type properties are automatically `required`. If you specifically set the `[Required]` attribute, then your `input`**must** have a `value` attribute which will get posted to the server and validated by the framework.

Comment: Your completely right but I need the `[Required]`AliRiza solved my Problem